# OTF files modified after compilation

Tags: java, javafx, truetype, apache-fop

This is something very weird and I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

I have a few OTF files on src/main/resources/report/fonts. These files are correct and work fine, but when I compile the application, they are modified (the size of the files increases 2x) and they are not valid anymore.

I am using Apache FOP and I get the following errors:

```
2014-05-27 11:34:30,145 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.TTFFile - Dirtab head not found.
2014-05-27 11:34:30,145 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.TTFFile - Dirtab maxp not found.
2014-05-27 11:34:30,145 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.TTFFile - Dirtab hhea not found.
2014-05-27 11:34:30,145 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.apache.fop.fonts.truetype.TTFFile - Dirtab hmtx not found
```

Now, if I, mannually change the fonts for the original files, everything works like a charm.

What is wrong? I have other files on the same folder and they are not modified.

**UPDATE**

This is how I am loading it, but I don't think the loading is the problem because, if I change the files for the original ones, it works.

```
fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("report/").toString().replace(":/", ":///"))
```

Comment: Can you show us some code on how you are trying to load the fonts ?

Comment: I guess the error is because the `Apache FOP` is **expecting** a `TTFFile`, whereas you are providing it with an `OTF` file

Comment: It works when I change the files for the original ones, which are OTF files.

Comment: What original files ?

Comment: The ones that are not modified. The ones that are in my original resources folder. As I said, after compilation, they are modified. If I, mannually, change those modified files for the original files, it works.

Comment: This is definitely not a `Javafx` problem and I am not experienced with Apache FOP, so may be you must wait for someone to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was a maven problem. You have to select the extensions of the files you are going to include. I knew this, but I did not remember I had done this in the past:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.otf</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.ttf</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.otf</include>
                <include>**/*.ttf</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```